# What are the values in a Transaction Datum?

Tags: cardano-node, transaction, transaction-metadata

Below is a link for the "inspect" window on Cardanoscan.
What are the values in the json?

(Example: 2486ff67c9772a45ed705adc7266c62ce8e2ad2e61c2656606ba966f)

https://cardanoscan.io/datumInspector?datum=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

Answer (score 1):

A guess:

The first set bytes (`2486...`) is the payment_cred key hash (pkh).
The second and third set bytes is a Cardano address that has been split.
The forth and fifth is also a Cardano address that has been split.

Comment: payment_cred is certainly part of it, and the addresses involved in the use of the outputs are indeed in there too it seems - I have finally begun to understand what I am looking at in there and how to decipher it. Thank you for responding.